# Dividing timestamps into weeks

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I'm looking to divide a span between two timestamps into weeks, in PHP.

Essentially, what I want to do is:

```
function divide_into_weeks($start_time, $end_time) {
  // Iterate back from the end time,
  // creating an array of timestamps broken into calendar weeks.
  $done = FALSE;
  $divider = $end_time;
  for ($i = 0; !$done; $i++) {
    $timeslots[$i]->end = $divider;
    // Set the start time to the start of the current week.
    $timeslots[$i]->start = strtotime("monday this week", $divider);
    if ($timeslots[$i]->start <= $start_time) {$done = TRUE;}
    // If we loop again, end the previous week one second before the start of this week.
    $divider = $timeslots[$i]->start - 1;
  }
}
```

However, the function hits an infinite loop.

Why? Because...

```
strtotime("monday this week", $monday_of_next_week -1) == $monday_of_last week;
```

... is true, strangely. This is unlike other strtotime operations I've tested. In other cases, you knock a second off, repeat, and it iterate back by one of whatever unit you've asked for. But not for Monday (or Sunday) of this week.

For example:

```
$today = strtotime("midnight");
$yesterday = strtotime("midnight", $today -1);
```

...produces sensible results.

But my attempts to use the same technique with "monday of this week" or "sunday of this week" have proven fruitless, so far.

So, can someone show how to iterate timestamps back by weeks?

Comment: What should the results of this look like if it worked?

Comment: You'd end up with an array of timestamps where each timestamp[$n]->start was midnight on monday of the start of the week, and timestamp[$n]->end was the second before midnight of the next week. (Special case: The end time of the initial timestamp, as written, will be the $end_time passed into the function.)

Comment: This is probably because weeks start on Sun? :)

Comment: Nope. I tried that, too, of course. "sunday of this week" usually returns the next coming Sunday. (Unless today is a Sunday, of course.) And stepping back from that Sunday is no more successful than stepping back from Mondays.

Comment: Nope, it's not that either. If you feed a "now" time in as the second parameter of "strtotime" it will be relative to that. However, simply taking -1 off the current Monday or Sunday to cross it over into the next week isn't enough. If you step it back by more than a day, you'll see it click over into a previous week. You could build a very clumsy workaround using that technique, of course.

Comment: You're right, it seems that you have to minus 86401 (i.e. a whole day + 1s), which is why I said that it's because weeks start on Sun.

Comment: Thanks for confirming a day-and-a-second as the breakpoint. I've put the workaround, however clumsy, in the code, and it indeed generates the desired result. I went ahead and posted that as the answer to the question, though if you want to repost it yourself, you can have the credit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you:

```php
function divide_into_weeks($start_time, $end_time, $tz) {
    $tz    = new DateTimezone($tz);
    $start = new DateTime("@$start_time");
    $end   = new DateTime("@$end_time");
    $start ->setTimezone($tz)->modify($start->format('o-\WW-1 00:00:00'));
    $end   ->setTimezone($tz)->modify($end  ->format('o-\WW-7'));
    $weeks = [];

    do {
        $weeks[] = [
            'start' => clone $start,
            'end' => new DateTime($start->format('o-\WW-7 23:59:59'), $tz),
        ];
        $start->modify('+7 day');
    } while ($start < $end);

    return $weeks;
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/137417)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the workaround that did the trick:
(With some of the irrelevant bits trimmed.)

```
function divide_timespan_into_units($start_second, $end_second, $time_unit) {
  $timeslots = array();
  // The time_formatter guides strtotime in what parts of a timestamp to trim off to leave timestamps split on calendar divisions.
  switch ($time_unit) {
    case "hour":
      $time_formatter = 'Y-m-d H:00:00';
      break;
    case "day":
      $time_formatter = 'Y-m-d 00:00:00'; 
      break;
    case "week":
      $time_formatter = "monday this week"; 
      break;
  }

  $done = FALSE;
  $divider = $end_second;

  for ($i = 0; !$done; $i++) {
    $timeslots[$i] = (object) array('end' => $divider);
    if ($time_unit == "week") {
      // Dividing timestamps up into calendar weeks requires special handling. 
      //
      // Note on the strange constants "86399" & "86400" in the two lines following:
      // This is a workaround for a fluke in how strtotime treats weeks:
      // 
      // strtotime can't decide if Sunday or Monday is the start of the week.
      // You have to force it by rolling back a full day plus one second from the start of Monday, to get into the previous week.
      //
      // Simply rolling back a second from Sunday by 1 second doesn't get you into the previous week,
      // because if you ask for "this Sunday" on any day other than Sunday, it will return the coming Sunday, not the past Sunday.
      // However, if you back up 1 second from the stroke of midnight Monday, and ask what week you're in, 
      // you'll be told that you're still in the same week.
      //
      // This nudge of an extra 86400 seconds (a full extra day) back and forth forces the week to click over.
      //
      // This will likely be settled in a later version of PHP, but as of 5.3.5 (when this is being coded) it's an issue.
      $timeslots[$i]->start = strtotime("monday this week", $divider-86400);
      $divider = $timeslots[$i]->start+86399;
    } else {
      $timeslots[$i]->start = strtotime(date($time_formatter, $divider));
    }
    if ($timeslots[$i]->start <= $start_second) {$done = TRUE;}
    $divider = $timeslots[$i]->start - 1;
  }
}
```